# how to simply use eval string formula with Abs() in js (google app script)

Tags: javascript, math, google-apps-script, eval

I see there is eval() to calculate string formula.

when i do `eval("546+613-(30644-30600)-(789+834-(30665-30600))")`, it works

but it failed for `eval("546+613-ABS(30644-30600)-(789+834-ABS(30665-30600))")`.

So, I would ask if eval support `abs()`? and is there simply way to calculate the failed case?

Or, i have to `Math.abs()`, and calculate it piece by piece?

Thanks a lots! I am new to calculation world in JS.

Comment: You don't need `eval` to do what you want.  `function test() {
  var a;
  
  a = 546 + 613 - Math.abs(30644-30600) - (789 + 834 - Math.abs(30665-30600));
  
  Logger.log(a)
  
}`

Comment: as i want to print the formula out, there is string version of the formula. and i will to reduce the coupling, so i would have simple way to calculate  the formula from string. it help me save the maintenance time of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `eval` is usually a very bad idea in terms of security (because it does run arbitrary code rather than just an arithmetic expression) but if you want to use it, what's the problem with first [replacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) all `"ABS"` with `"Math.abs"` in the string before calling the `eval`?